# Can't using MySQL command line with uWamp

Tags: uwamp

i need to use MySQL commande line for a script but with MySQL 5.6.X login return :

> Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

The full command i need is :

> mysql --login-path=mypath -e "My Statement"

To solved the problem i need [msql_config_editor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) but it's not include with uWamp.

Can i add it or do i need to change uWamp for an other WAMP package ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by installing WAMP with which I generated the file .mylogin.cnf

Just stop WAMP and start uWamp and it's works.